# How to run worker process on iis under client identity without asking for password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, windows-authentication

I want to run an web application hosted on IIS and it should run under the client who is currently using the web application. It must work with client's windows authentication.Suppose, I have to execute .net web application on server then the application must run under that (particular) identity. Windows authentication for the client must be passed to IIS to run the requested application.

Comment: Use Windows Authentication Mode in your config file. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication

Comment: it runs perfectly when executed locally but when it is hosted on server then worker process are running under APPLICATION POOL IDENTITY which I want to run with credentials of client without prompting them for password. I meant once client log in to his system he should be able to run application on server.